# How can I choose the cluster with the highest WCSS value via sumd and idx?

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am applying the bisecting k-means algorithm to cluster users for each antenna beam.

The problem arises after splitting the cluster containing all users in two. In fact at this point I have to go to select the cluster with the highest `wcss` but I don't know how to do it.
I had thought about taking advantage of the `sumd` and `idx` values.

```matlab
function [Clustering, SYSTEM] = CLUST_Bkmeans(kk, SYSTEM, USERS, ChannelMatrix)
    Clustering = cell(SYSTEM.Nbeams,1);
    UserPool = (1:SYSTEM.Nusers)';
    
    Channel_real = real(ChannelMatrix);
    Channel_imag = imag(ChannelMatrix);
    
    avg_clusterSize = kk;
    
    for ii=1:SYSTEM.Nbeams              
        Users          = UserPool(USERS.BeamIndex==ii);

        %Matrix of channel coefficient built as [real part | imaginary part]
        Users_real = Channel_real(Users,:);
        Users_imag = Channel_imag(Users,:);
        
        X = [Users_real Users_imag];
        
        SYSTEM.Nclusters(ii) = ceil(size(Users,1)/avg_clusterSize);
        
        Clustering{ii} = cell(SYSTEM.Nclusters(ii),1);
        
        %Bisecting k-means clustering of X 
        
        [idx,C,sumd] = kmeans(X,2); %first division in two cluster
    
        for pp = 3:SYSTEM.Ncluster(ii)                             
            %kmeans applied to cluster with higher WCSS
        end
        
        % silhouette(X,idx)
        % xlabel('Silhouette Value')
        % ylabel('Cluster')
    
        for jj = 1:SYSTEM.Nclusters(ii)
            Clustering{ii}{jj,1} = Users(idx==jj)';
        end    
    end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. What is a "wcss" and how do you want to take advantage of `sumd` and `idx`? Can you please [edit] your question to clarify this?

Comment: wcss is the meaning of Within-Cluster Sum of Square. After the first division into two clusters I have to select the one with the highest WCSS. So I thought I'd use those two values ​​to figure it out.

Comment: Again: could you please take the [tour], read up on [ask] and [edit] the question to include that information, *including* what you thought to do with those two values? As it stands, your question remains unclear.

Comment: @beaker how can i run each cluster with pdist? My problem is just that. I can't figure out how to select individual clusters and then iterate again.

Comment: @EmanueleGandolfi Actually, I was wrong.The documentation for [`kmeans`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html#buefs04-sumd) says that the default metric used is the squared Euclidean distance. `idx` and `sumd` should be all we need.

Comment: @beaker ok, so how could i get the users who belong only to the cluster with the highest WCSS? My idea was to subset the initial dataset, i.e. use the max (sumd) function to evaluate which cluster is least dense and then assign its users to a new set. But this last step I am unable to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noted, [`kmeans`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html#d123e555216) returns the cluster indices and the sum of squared distances within each cluster (along with the centroid of each cluster, but we don't need that in this instance).

Finding the cluster with the highest WCSS is easy. [`sumd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html#buefs04-sumd) is a k x 1 vector where k is the number of clusters. With just two clusters, you can easily select which one is larger, but if you have more clusters, you can use the `I` (index) return value from [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html):

```
[~, max_wcss_cluster] = max(sumd);   % index is the second return value
```

At some point, you're probably going to need to know which observations in `X` are in a particular cluster. To list those rows of `X`, you would use the `idx` vector returned by `kmeans` and logical indexing:

```
cluster_number = 2;   % find all observations in cluster 2
my_cluster = X(idx==cluster_number, :);
```

Comment: I have implemented this code in my program but I get the following error: The logical indices in position 1 contain a true value outside of the array bounds. More precisely when he executes this line of code: my_cluster = X (idx == cluster_number, :); how can i solve that?

Comment: Debug one step at a time. Check that the size of `sumd` is equal to the number of clusters. Check that `max_wcss_cluster` is the **index** of the maximum value in `sumd`. Check that `X` and `idx` have the same number of rows. Make sure that the vector `(idx == cluster_number)` has the same number of rows as `X` and `idx`.

Comment: yes I have Debug one step at a time and I noticed that sumd has many more columns than the initial two clusters. Can I solve by using the reshape function? to understand better I created another question where I show the code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72618500/kmeans-error-the-logical-indices-in-position-1-contain-a-true-value-outside-of