# Kmeans error: The logical indices in position 1 contain a true value outside of the array bounds

Tags: k-means

```
X = rand(1482,74);

nCluster = 12;
[idx,C,sumd] = kmeans(X,2);



%%
for pp = 3 : nCluster

[~, index_max_cluster] = max(sumd);
   max_wcss_cluster = X(idx==index_max_cluster, :);
    
   [idx,C,sumd] = kmeans(max_wcss_cluster,2);
end
```

I need to bisecting K-means to a dataset, but I can't resolve this error. Maybe it's because I have to merge all the data into a cluster first?
How can I solve?

Comment: When you loop, you need to update `X` to be the observations of the cluster you are actually using. I would change `max_wcss_cluster = X(idx==index_max_cluster, :);` to `X = X(idx==index_max_cluster, :);`

Comment: ok and so i have to write '[idx,C,sumd] = kmeans(X,2);' in the final line of the loop, right?

Comment: In case the number of clusters exceeds the number of rows of X how could I act?

Comment: If the number of clusters exceeds the number of observations, you're trying to put 2 points in 3 clusters (for example). That doesn't make sense.